# $X,Y$ be normed-linear spaces , $Y$ finite dimensional , $T: X \to Y$ be a non-continuous linear map , then is $\ker T$ dense in $X$?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $X,Y$ be normed-linear spaces ( over $\mathbb R$) , $Y$ is finite dimensional and  $T: X \to Y$ be a linear map which is not continuous ; I know that then $\ker T$ is not closed in $X$ ; my question is , is $\ker T$ then dense in $X$ ?  If $Y=\mathbb R$ then I can prove that the kernel is indeed dense , but I have no idea for the general case . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Take $Y = \mathbb{R}^2$, and look at the component functionals of $T$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : But what is the guarantee that all the components are not continuous ? I can only figure out that at least one component is not continuous ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\dim Y > 1$, it does not follow that the kernel is dense. Since $Y$ is finite-dimensional, we can without loss of generality assume $Y = \mathbb{R}^n$, and then a discontinuous linear map $X \to Y$ corresponds to an $n$-tuple $(T_1,...,T_n)$ of linear functionals, such that *at least one* of the $T_k$ is discontinuous. Further, we have

$$\ker T = \bigcap_{k = 1}^n \ker T_k,$$

and thus it follows that $\ker T$ is not dense if there is (at least) one $j$ such that $T_j$ is a nonzero continuous linear functional, since then $\overline{\ker T} \subset \ker T_j \subsetneqq X$.

It is not necessary that one of the component functionals is continuous, however: If $\lambda \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a discontinuous linear functional and $\mu \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ a nonzero continuous linear functional, then $$T \colon X \to \mathbb{R}^2,\; x \mapsto (\lambda(x), \lambda(x) + \mu(x))$$ has no continuous component, but $\ker T = \ker \lambda \cap \ker \mu$ is not dense.